Cylinder inscribed in a cone without calculus
Let a cylinder be inscribed inside a a cone. Find the height and radius of the cylinder that has the biggest volume for a given cone height and radius.
Here is the a simple calculus approach:
Let the radius on the cone be $r$ and its height $h$ and the radius of the cylinder $x$ and its height $y$.The volume we are looking to maximize is $$V_{cyl}=\pi x^2y$$
To do this, we must relate $x, y, r, h:$

We can see ,from similarity that $$\frac{\text{height of triangle above cylinder}
}{\text{base of Triangle above cylinder}}=\frac{\text{height of full triangle}}{\text{base of full triangle}}$$ Therefore, $$\frac{h-y}{2x}=\frac{h}{2r}\implies y=h(1-\frac{x}{r})$$
Thus $$V_{cyl}=\pi x^2h(1-\frac{x}{r})=\pi h(x^2-\frac{x^3}{r})$$
To find a maximum, take the derivative and solve for when the derivative equals zero:
$$\frac{dV}{dx}=0 \iff x=0\lor \frac{2r}{3}$$
excluding $x=0$ we get $V_{max}=\pi h r^2\frac{h}{27}$ And from this equation we can solve for any value we are asked
Q: Does anyone know of a way to find this result without calculus?

typo - I think you meant to write $$V_{max}=\pi h r^2\frac{4}{27}$$

I'm not sure what your intended audience is, but maximizing $V_{cyl}$ is equivalent to maximizing $4\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^2(r-x)$. By the AM-GM inequality, the maximum is achieved when $\frac{x}{2}=r-x$.

$V_{cyl}=\pi h(x^2-\frac{x^3}{r})=\frac{\pi h}{r}(x^2r-x^3)$. The positive constant $\frac{\pi h}{r}$ doesn't affect the value at which the function reaches its maximum, so that maximizing $V_{cyl}$ is equivalent to maximizing $(x^2r-x^3)$. We then rewrite this as $x^2(r-x)=\left(2\frac{x}{2}\right)^2(r-x)=4\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^2(r-x)$.

@Ert33 But we also have $x^2(r-x)=\left(3\frac{x}{3}\right)^2(r-x)=9\left(\frac{x}{3}\right)^2(r-x)$.

@Dan yes but the point is that we want the sum of the three numbers we are multiplying to be constant in order to use AM-GM. In your example, $\frac{x}{3}+\frac{x}{3}+r-x$ is not constant.

@Ert33 Indeed, that is the key.

@Ert33 gave a nice answer using the AM-GM. If the intended audience is not familiar with the AM-GM inequality, here is another approach.

You have:
$$V=\pi hx^2\left(1-\dfrac{x}{r}\right)$$
$$V=-\dfrac{\pi h}{r}x^2(x-r)$$
This is a cubic function with leading coefficient $-\dfrac{\pi h}{r}$, a double root at $x=0$, and a single root at $x=r$. Here is the graph:

We want to find the coordinates of the local maximum point, without calculus, as requested.
Translate the curve down so that the local maximum point becomes a tangent point with the $x$-axis.

The new curve's equation can be expressed as $V=\color{red}{-\dfrac{\pi h}{r}x^2(x-r)-k}$ for some $k$, and it can also be expressed as $V=\color{red}{-\dfrac{\pi h}{r}(x-a)(x-b)^2}$ for some $a$ and $b$, where $b$ is the $x$-coordinate of the local maximum point.
Set these two expressions equal:
$$-\dfrac{\pi h}{r}x^2(x-r)-k=-\dfrac{\pi h}{r}(x-a)(x-b)^2$$
Divide both sides by $\dfrac{-\pi h}{r}$ and expand:
$$x^3-rx^2+\frac{kr}{\pi h}=x^3-(a+2b)x^2+(2ab+b^2)x-ab^2$$
Equate coefficients on the left and right:
$$x^2: \space r=a+2b$$
$$x^1: \space 0=2ab+b^2$$
Solving these two equations together (keeping in mind that $a<0$ and $0<b<r$), we get $a=-\dfrac13r$ and $b=\dfrac23r$.
So the volume of the cylinder is maximized when $x=\dfrac{2}{3}r$ and $y=\dfrac{1}{3}h$.
The maximum volume of the cylinder is $k=-ab^2\left(\dfrac{\pi h}{r}\right)=\dfrac{4\pi}{27}hr^2$.

There is another solution to the equated coefficients of $a = r, b = 0$, but that gives the original picture $(k = 0)$ and corresponds to the minimum at $x = 0$.

Given:
1. Cone:
Radius = $r$,
Height = $h$.
2. Cylinder (inscribed in the cone):
Radius = $x$,
Height = $y$.
We aim to determine $x$ and $y$ that maximize the volume of the cylinder.

Relating  and  using similar triangles
In a vertical cross-section of the cone:
The full cone has a height $h$  and base radius $r$.
At a height $y$  from the cone's apex, the cone's cross-section radius decreases linearly.
$\frac{x}{r} = \frac{h - y}{h}$.
From similar triangles, the ratio of the reduced radius $x$  of the cylinder to the cone’s base radius  $r$ equals the ratio of the remaining height $h-y$ to the total height :
$\frac{x}{r} = \frac{h - y}{h}$.
Rearranging for , we get:
$x = r \left( \frac{h - y}{h} \right)$.

Volume of the cylinder
The volume  of the cylinder is:
$V = \pi x^2 y$.
Substitute  into the equation for :
$V = \pi \left( r \frac{h - y}{h} \right)^2 y$.
Simplify:
$V = \pi r^2 \frac{(h - y)^2}{h^2} y$.

Maximizing the volume without calculus
We now analyze the expression for :
$V = \frac{\pi r^2}{h^2} (h - y)^2 y$.
To maximize  without calculus, we rely on symmetry and balance in the problem.
Here is a point to note
The volume depends on the product of:

$y$ (the cylinder's height),

$(h-y)^2$ (the square of the distance from the cylinder's top to the cone's base).


For such products, the optimal balance occurs when the height $y$  is one-third of the cone's height $h$ :
$y = \frac{h}{3}$.

Solving for the radius
Substitute  into the equation for :
$x = r \left( \frac{h - y}{h} \right)$.
Simplify:
$x = r \left( \frac{h - \frac{h}{3}}{h} \right)$.
$x = r \left( \frac{\frac{2h}{3}}{h} \right)$.
$x = \frac{2r}{3}$.

Final Answer
The dimensions of the cylinder that maximize its volume are:
Height $y = \frac{h}{3}$,
Radius $x = \frac{2r}{3}$,
That was my approach without Calculus. Hope you would like it.

Quote: "For such products, the optimal balance occurs when the height $y$ is one-third of the cone's height $h$." Yes, but how do you know?
